# How to use a pair of single-quotes inside double qoutes in bash?

Tags: mysql, bash, escaping

I am going to write a bash script to manipulate user's data on mysql DB.

Here is the problem. I need to pass a variable's value into a Mysql query string:

```
read USERNAME;
echo  "USE drupdb; SELECT uid  FROM users WHERE name= '%USERNAME';"  > /tmp/query.sql ;
```

Whatever combinations that I've used (including backslashs befor single-quotes to scape them) did not do the trick. I still get something other than the value of %USERNAME inside the query.sql.

I appreciate your hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `$` to dereference a variable. Change `%USERNAME` to `$USERNAME` and everything should work fine:

```
read USERNAME;
echo  "USE drupdb; SELECT uid  FROM users WHERE name= '$USERNAME';"
```